# column count doesn't match the value count at row 1_database insert error

Tags: php, mysql, function, insert

Been working on this for a while. For some reason even though I have enough values and columns, I get "column count doesn't match value count at row 1" error.

I tried passing $values as array-- doesn't work because its array.
Tried putting $values and $kk inside '', but didn't work.
This version of code yielded least amount of errors.

```
<?php



    $dbh = new mysqli("localhost", "admin", "password", "database");

    $dta= mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM agents");

    include_once("class.php");

    $agntProperties = new agntObjects;

    $ary = array ($agntProperties->agntID=$_GET['id'] => array(
    $agntProperties->agntFName=$_GET['fname'],//error occurs"unknown column in field list
    $agntProperties->agntMiddleInitial=$_GET['mname'],
    $agntProperties->agntLastname = $_GET['lname'],
    $agntProperties->agntBusPhone = $_GET['agntbusphone'],
    $agntProperties->agntEmail = $_GET['email'],
    $agntProperties->agntPosition = $_GET['agntpos'],
    $agntProperties->agencyId = $_GET['agencyId']));

    $arryy = array ((int)$_GET['id'],$_GET['fname'],$_GET['mname'],$_GET['lname'],
    $_GET['agntbusphone'],$_GET['email'],$_GET['agntpos'],(int)$_GET['agencyId']);







function insertDta(array $agntArray, $database, $table)
{
    $agntProperties = $GLOBALS['agntProperties'];

    $database=$GLOBALS['dbh'];//it should be something that changes depending on agent


    $agntdata= get_class($agntProperties)::$fields; // $fields properties are below for reference

    //public static $fields = array ('AgentId','AgtFirstName', 'AgtMiddleInitial', 'AgtLastName','AgtBusPhone','AgtEmail', 'AgtPosition','AgencytId')

    $agntprops= implode(',', $agntdata);

    $vals= array();

    foreach($agntArray as $k=>$v)
    {
        $kk=$k;
        $vals= $v;        

    }

    $values= implode(',',$vals);


    $sql = "INSERT INTO agents ($agntprops) VALUES ($kk,'$values')";


    $result= mysqli_query($database,$sql);

    if($result)
    {
        echo "all good";
    }else {
        echo "update failed"."<br>";
        echo  mysqli_error($database);
    }


}


    insertDta($ary,"", "");

    $dbh-> close();


?>
```

Expected results would be: being able to insert all the values such as agentid, firstname, etc to database.

Comment: in the loop `foreach($agntArray as $k=>$v)` it looks like you are overwriting the values of `$kk` and `$vals` and then mmediately after do `$values= implode(',',$vals);`

Comment: vals initially go in as an array in the loop, so stating that $kk is the key and $vals(array) is value of the key. outside the loop, I converted $vals to string that came as (fname, middlename...such). In the insert function it looks something like-- Insert into database (id, firstname, ...) VALUES (id, fname, ...). which to me looks okay, but i still get error